# Visualizing continuous and revolute joint types in rviz

Tags: ros, joint, rviz, urdf, joint-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When creating a URDF file for a robot with a head on a pan and tilt mechanism, whenever I try to use a joint type "continuous" or "revolute" in a manner similar to that shown in the tutorials the model is displayed within Rviz as a disorganized jumble.  If I change the joint type to "fixed" then the model displays normally.  The model also seems to check out ok using check_urdf, and no URDF errors show up when Rviz is loading.  This seems to be a bug, since the same thing happens with the tutorial file 06-flexible.urdf

I'm using the current cturtle full binary installation on Ubuntu 10.10.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9130/visualizing-continuous-and-revolute-joint-types-in-rviz/) by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 995 on 2011-02-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For non-fixed joints you need some source that publishes the joint states, otherwise the model cannot be displayed correctly, as the state of the joints is unknown.

A simple launch files for testing a URDF model in rviz using the joint_state_publisher looks like this:

```
<launch>
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find yourrobot_urdf)/yourrobot/robot_base.urdf.xacro" />
<param name="use_gui" value="True"/>
<node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" ></node>
<node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" />
<node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" />
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2011-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-02-19**:
Ah, ok, that could be it!

**Comment by [Yantian_Zha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13706/yantian_zha/) on 2014-04-21**:
Should I change robot_description to others? I got error "Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: ...". I'm using Groovy. Thanks!

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-04-21**:
Hard to say what is wrong in your case without more information. You should probably create a new question with a detailed problem description.